# node child_process gives valid output in stderr for mongodump

Tags: node.js, child-process, mongodump

I'm executing `mongodump` command from nodejs `child_process`.

I have tried both `exec` and `spawn`, but the progress printed by `mongodump` is hitting the `data` event of `stderr` instead of `stdout`

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    ls    = exec('mongodump --gzip --archive="/home/test-machine/test.archive" --db myDB');

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code.toString());
});
```

The mongodump is not crashing, or throwing any error, its executing as it should. But somehow nodejs is treating the output as stderr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongodump` writes log messages to `stderr`, which isn't very uncommon, although it makes parsing the output for errors a bit harder because you need to manually filter out the error messages.

Comment: any reason they do that? you said its not very uncommon to do so, can you please tell me why is that?

Comment: `mongodump` has an option to dump to `stdout`, so log messages would interfere with that, hence the use of `stderr`. Lots of tools that write their output to `stdout` (or have an option to do so) use that convention.