Piped stderr but mongodump stdout lines appear in error log file
I have tried the below two options in crontab and expecting to get only stderr in the log file. However, some non-error lines related to mongodump command in the script file appear in the log file. I have seen various posts on stderr piping here, but couldn't get what I wanted. Where am I going wrong?
The two crontab options that are tried:
0 0 * * * /root/scripts/dev-vps_backup.sh >> logfile.log 2>&1 > /dev/null

0 0 * * * /root/scripts/dev-vps_backup.sh 2>&1 >> all.log | tee -a all.log err.log >&2

the bash script file:
#!/bin/bash

set -e

#start time var
start_time=$(TZ=Asia/Calcutta date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S)
echo "Started Script: " $(basename "$0") "@ $start_time"

#########UPDATE THIS###########
### setting up variables here
######################## END of UPDATE

#create backup folders
mkdir -p $local_backupfolder
mkdir -p $local_dumps_backupfolder
mkdir -p $local_assets_backupfolder

# remote backup storage
remote_base_backupfolder=root@$remote_IP:/root/r-backups/$vps_name


# mongodump
gzfile=$local_dumps_backupfolder/$vps_name--dump--$start_time.gz
dumpMsg="$vps_name mongodump StartTime:$start_time, EndTime:"

if mongodump --gzip --archive=$gzfile ; then   ### THIS generates lines that are shown in stderr file
  echo "DONE: $dumpMsg $(TZ=Asia/Calcutta date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S)"
else
  echo "ERR: $dumpMsg $(TZ=Asia/Calcutta date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S)" | mailx -s "ERR: $vps_name mongodump" $recipient_email
  exit
fi

zipMsg1="$vps_name - $app_name1 - ZIP file for folder: $local_assets_folder1. StartTime:$start_time, EndTime:"

if zip -r $local_assets_backupfolder/$vps_name--$app_name1--assets-$(TZ=Asia/Calcutta date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S).zip $local_assets_folder1 ; then
   echo "DONE: $zipMsg1 $(TZ=Asia/Calcutta date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S)"
else
   echo "ERR: $zipMsg1 $(TZ=Asia/Calcutta date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S)" | mailx -s "ERR: $vps_name - $app_name1 - assets local ZIP" $recipient_email
   exit
fi

some1-some_command  # to generate error

## some more lines


err.log file:
2024-08-02T10:33:01.116+0200    writing admin.system.version to archive '/root/backups/dumps/fvc1-vps--dump--02-08-2024_14-03-01.gz'
2024-08-02T10:33:01.118+0200    done dumping admin.system.version (1 document)
2024-08-02T10:33:01.118+0200    writing myca.syslogs to archive '/root/backups/dumps/fvc1-vps--dump--02-08-2024_14-03-01.gz'
.....some more lines related to mongodump command....
/root/scripts/fvc1-vps_backup.sh: line 61: some1-some_command: command not found

all.log file has the additional lines related to echo command and zip command.
EXPECTED: Only the last line in err.log file - which is the error. How do I achieve this?
UPDATE
tried this crontab:
59 11 * * * /root/scripts/fvc1-vps_backup.sh >> /root/scripts/logfile.log

resultant logfile:
Started Script:  fvc1-vps_backup.sh @ 02-08-2024_15-29-01
DONE: fvc1-vps mongodump StartTime:02-08-2024_15-29-01, EndTime: 02-08-2024_15-29-01
  adding: root/jobs/assets/ (stored 0%)
  adding: root/jobs/assets/tempfiles/ (stored 0%)
        ...... some more lines resulting from zip command.....
  adding: root/jobs/assets/invoiceDocs/ (stored 0%)
DONE: fvc1-vps - jobs - ZIP file for folder: /root/jobs/assets. StartTime:02-08-2024_15-29-01, EndTime: 02-08-2024_15-29-19

The log file doesnot include mongodump related lines. That means these lines are going to stderr (as show in the first log file result). Not sure why?

@jhnc I am new to bash script. How do I redirect logged output of mongodump?

does mongodump output to stderr or stdout?

To rearticulate the first comment, the reason this is happening is that you are specifically requesting it with 2>&1. Don't do that if you don't want that.

@tripleee actually I'm wrong, neither command shown dups the descriptors together. the first is equivalent to 2>>logfile.log 1>/dev/null but the second actually looks like it might do what's wanted - but only if mongodump's output is going to stdout

With the conflicting redirections, what exactly it does is probably not well-defined and system-dependent.

@tripleee they don't conflict, the operations are well-defined - earlier ones get updated by later ones "If more than one redirection operator is specified with a command, the order of evaluation is from beginning to end."

ran the bash script without any redirection. Mongodump related lines do not appear in stdout !!!! not sure why

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128598/node-child-process-gives-valid-output-in-stderr-for-mongodump  this briefly discusses this issue.   "mongodump writes log messages to stderr, which isn't very uncommon". Will try to manually filter those lines using "dump"

The second set of redirections appear suitable for what you want:
shellscript 2>&1 >> all.log | tee -a all.log err.log >&2

However it relies on output of all individual commands inside shellscript going where you want them (stdout or stderr).
It appears that mongodump writes to stderr. If you want its output to appear in all.log but not err.log, you need to redirect its stderr to stdout. For example:
if mongodump --gzip --archive=$gzfile 2>&1 ; then


Yes... this worked if mongodump --gzip --archive=$gzfile 2>&1 ; for both the crontab options

Just a thought. Although this has solved my problem, which was caused due to mongodump writing its stdout to stderr. In case a real error occurs in mongodump this solution will remove that too from stderr.

@hemant indeed. however it should still log to all.log (unlike the other crontab version where you simply discarded stdout)
